# Executable not found in Visual Studio solution when I try to run the code

Tags: visual-studio, video-codecs

I have a Visual Studio Video Codec solution wherein I need to generate 5 frames of data. As far as I know the code is code with no errors or warnings with respect to the process flow. However, when I try to run without debug it generates an error saying that the executable for debug not found. Can someone help me with a solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come across such an error while running my solution as well on Visual Studio. Do not worry, the answer is simple either the executable is being used by some process or the solution is not able to locate the path for the executable. A simple solution for this error, go to the path where your previous executable is generated. Rename the executable to something else. Once done compile your code again and run it, it will work. I have done it multiple times, so it will work for your solution as well.